# Input tag not working in specific Django project

Tags: python, html, django, forms, input

I am practicing Django and now working on some project. In this project, my input type isn't responding to clicks. I have tried to put same input form on other project and it's working. But on current project it isn't. Can't figure it out why.

Html code:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Contact">
</form>
```

views.py

```
def home(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        pass
else:
    form = ContactForm()

context = {
    "Welcome_text": "Sveiki atvykę",
    "form": form
}

return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

Comment: Does it do anything? does it hit a breakpoint in the view? you may want to remove the whole `action=""` since it isn't needed

Comment: did you to debug that? Is your code reading in that view upon hitting 'Contact' button? Try to put print statement before 'if request.method == 'POST':'

Comment: I think the data which you are posting in the form might not be valid and again and again the code is going in the else block to display the blank form. Use pdb and check weather the form is valid or not.

Comment: If i write "print(request.method)", it prints GET,
also, "print(form.is_valid())" prints FALSE. When i click on button, nothing happens.